# Issue with Sql query: count distinct row values relative to other row value

Tags: mysql, sql, select, count

I have the following table:

```
name        category    posts
------------------------------
Client A    01          5348
Client A    05          2584
Client B    02          105
Client C    14          10558
Client C    16          511
Client D    01          4863
Client D    01          1823
```

Now I'd like to select those rows where:

- the client is present in only one category. That means both Client B and client D are still possible.

AND

- this category is "01". So in the end the desired output would be:

  ```
  Client D    01          4863
  Client D    01          1823
  ```

The query I had in mind:

```
SELECT name, category, posts
FROM exampletable
WHERE (count number of present distinct categories for each name = '1' AND category='01');
```

The problem is that I don't know how to translate "*count number of present distinct categories for each name*" into a correct sql code. Anybody who can help me out with this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use sub-query to achieve this:

```
Select e.name, e.category, e.posts from exampletable e
where e.name not in
(select e1.name from exampletable e1 where e.name = e1.name and e.category <> e1.category) 
and e.category = '01'
```

Explanation: The subquery will return all those names which **do not have one-is-to-one relation** with the category, so they can be eliminated using `NOT IN` and further filter can be applied using `AND category = '01'`

Answer (score 0):

Tested and verified.

```
create table #t (
 name varchar(100),
 category varchar(2),
 posts int
);

insert into #t
select
'Client A', '01',  5348
union all select
'Client A', '05',  2584
union all select
'Client B', '02',  105
union all select
'Client C', '14',  10558
union all select
'Client C', '16',  511
union all select
'Client D', '01',  4863
union all select
'Client D', '01',  1823;

select
    name,
    category,
    posts
from
    #t
where name in
    (
        select
            name
        from
            #t
        group by
            name
        having
            1 = count(distinct category)
    ) 
    and '01' = category;
```

Output:

```
Client D    01  4863
Client D    01  1823
```